# How to program an NFC tag to a certain macro?

Tags: python, android, ios, macros, nfc

is there any way that I can program an NFC tag to perform an action when it touches a phone,so that it does something for example opens an app and then in that app it clicks a button. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes you can get a NFC tag to start any App on Android and iOS (But how to configure the Tag is different between the two OS's)

Then click a Button on Any App is a No.

[Android start Any App with AAR record details](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/connectivity/nfc/nfc#aar)

[iOS start Any App with universal links details](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/corenfc/adding_support_for_background_tag_reading?language=objc)

If the App started is your own then you program it to read more data from the NFC Tag and do the same action as clicking the Button would do (without actually clicking the Button)